# VBA - How can I get all Mondays in a month then multiply to working hours?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how to get the total of Mondays in a month then multiply by working hours.

This is my example code it works but it counts wrong output:

```
  If UCase(val) Like "EVERY MONDAY" Then
   Dim numString As Integer
   Dim strDays() As String
   Dim wordCount As Long

   numString = 2

   strDays = VBA.Split(val, " ")
   wordCount = UBound(strDays)
   strWhEveryDay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Cells(X, 4).Value
   strWhEveryDay = strWhEveryDay * var_month
   Debug.Print "Every = " & strWhEveryDay
```

Explanation:

- It depends on the user if what they like to input in a TEXTBOX. However, the CALCULATION it depends on the date where the user input in TEXTBOX.
- I have Textbox which is the target month where the user input the format of date like this:

  **Jan-2023 or Feb-2023 **
- I have a table like this:

  Place this text in a table start in Column B Row 2:

  ```
  **every Monday**
  ```

  Place this text in a table Column D Row 4:

  ```
  **1.2**
  ```
- All I need is to get all the total of Mondays based on the given month and year. The calculation of the days in a table of "every Monday" once I change the text from "every Monday" to "every Tuesday" so the calculation will adjust or automatically knows where the calculation days start to end:
- Example of expected calculation: **every Monday** (January 2023 = 5 Days) * 1.2 so, the expected result will be 5.

**Note:** use Debug.Print to see the result or output

Comment: [Count the number of Mondays in a month](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_count_month_mondays.html)

Comment: @TinMan I already check this example and it didn't work on my end.

Comment: So functions like networkdays.intl can deal with holidays - why not specify the other 6 days as holidays... Then you can have a 7 days in a list with a 1 or 0 to include them or not.

Comment: Maybe something like this ? `m = "Jan-23": dy = "Monday"` m is the month inputted by the user in a cell or in a textbox, dy is the day name to count in m. Then loop from 1 to the end of date of m to count how many dy exist in the loop into cnt variable : `For i = 1 To Format(Application.EoMonth("1-" & m, 0), "dd"): If Format(i & "-" & m, "dddd") = dy Then cnt = cnt + 1: Next i` ---> the cnt will be 5. If you change the dy into "Saturday", the cnt will be 4. If the string with "Every" .... `dy = Replace("Every Monday", "Every ", "")`

Comment: Your expected result should be 6 based on the calculation you show.

Answer (score 1):

So, using networkdays.intl() as suggested in my comment:

```
NETWORKDAYS.INTL($A$3,$A$33,"0111111",)
```

[image]

The result shown is 5, which is correct by inspection, for cells A3:A33 the long date format was used.

So multiplying by 1.2 is:

```
NETWORKDAYS.INTL($A$3,$A$33,"0111111",)*1.2
```

and 5 * 1.2 = 6

Also, the string "0111111" can be put in cell F5 and referred to so it is easier to edit.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know to recognise any day of the week is the following:

```
=WEEKDAY(B2,2)
```

The "2" means that weekdays are counted, starting with "Monday" as 1, "Tuesday" as 2, ...

So, if you want to know if your date is a Monday, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B2,2)=1,...)
```

This can easily be translated into VBA, using a standard `IF`-clause.

Comment: Also you could use countif() to count the 1's ie Mondays.

Comment: @SolarMike: that was indeed my idea: once you know how to recognise a Monday (using the `=WeekDay()` function, you can use it in `IF()`, `SumIF()`, `CountIFS()`, ... functions.

Comment: Yes, I came back to yours as well - playing as some people pay on the Fridays of a month or the last Friday of a month. Building yet another exercise for my students...